# C# Unix timestamp

Tags: c#, mysql, unix

What I want to do is block a user from doing something for 24 hours after they have reached a limit. I have coded the limit part, I just need to know how to block it if it hasn't been 24 hours.

Here is an example on how I want to do it. Update the user's account using a query and set the timestamp (Unix) to that time. Then I don't know how I can get another timestamp of the time they try to do it and check if the new timestamp is 24 hours between the last?

I have medium experience with C# but timestamps is one section I know nothing about with c#. Ss there anyone here that can help or provide a good tutorial? Or an idea on how I can learn more about it. I'm looking for the best way to do this. If Unix timestamps aren't it then please let me know and provide me with a better way if you can.

```
//Example
if (!CODE_HERE_FOR_NOT_24_HOURS)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You have reached your limit for today. Try again tomorow");
    return; 
}
else
{
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. It has to be updated in a database due to my application restarting multiple times a day and i wouldn't be able to save it, Please tell me if im wrong with this.

Comment: @AshSmith You should be able to save a DateTime in the DB without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, you'd typically use `DateTime.UtcNow`, and use a `DateTime`, not a unix timestamp.

You can always check to see if its been less than 24 hours via:

```
if (timeStamp > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
{
   // It's been less than 24 hours
}
```

Comment: Does this still apply to my update on my question? I have explained that it has to be updated in the database due to emulator reloading multiple times a day.

Comment: Would the timeStamp variable be the DateTime.Now that i save?

Comment: It would apply, but you would also need the additional step of saving `timeStamp` to the database, and loading it from the database when the app starts.

Comment: @AshSmith Yes - The DB should be able to store a DateTime without issue.